# mysql delete trigger affecting table being used for query

Tags: mysql, triggers

When I delete an influence row, I want to mark the star being influenced that it needs a recalc (recalcs are moderately expensive, so are deferred to later, and I don't want to recalc stars that aren't needed).  So I have a trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER stationinfluence_cleanup after delete ON stationinfluence
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    UPDATE star s SET s.needs_recalc = 1 WHERE s.id = OLD.star_id;
END //
```

This works fine if I know which `stationinfluence` rows need to be deleted:

```
mysql> delete from stationinfluence where stationinfluence.station_id = 12024 and star_id in (1);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)
```

But if I don't know and want to calculate them (they're any stars outside of a range from a center point which may currently be influenced, if that helps), mySQL gives an error:

```
mysql> delete from stationinfluence where stationinfluence.station_id = 12024 and exists (select 1 from star where star.id = `stationinfluence`.`star_id` and pow(pow(star.x - -6,2)+pow(star.y-5,2),0.5) > 300);
ERROR 1442 (HY000): Can't update table 'star' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.
```

This isn't the end of the world to query the IDs I need to delete and then delete them, but it's an extra round-trip to the database I'd rather avoid.

Is there something I can change in either the trigger or the `delete` statement to get this done?

Answer (score 0):

I see two other options besides getting ids by separate query:

- create field `range` in `stationinfluence` to eliminate `star` table from delete query. e.g.

  ```
  DELETE FROM stationinfluence WHERE stationinfluence.station_id = 12024 and range>300
  ```

  this option needs to create trigger on insert into `stationinfluence` to calculate `range` bases on star with `star_id`; trigger on update on star table if `x`,`y` are changed; and so on...
- store `needs_recalc` in separate table, and in trigger:

  ```
  UPDATE star_recalc s SET s.needs_recalc = 1 WHERE s.id = OLD.star_id;
  ```

  or better (`star_recalc` like log table, just inserts and deletes after recalc, with possible unique `star_id`):

  ```
  INSERT into star_recalc (star_id) values(OLD.star_id);
  ```